# Find the ratio of slope

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

> [image]

Note : Elevation $46000$ and all dimention in $mm$ (milimeter)

The pipe  will be installed on a surface of module structure, that module structure has different surface.

> I want to know  " ratio of the slope from point $A$ to point $B$ " and at the time of installation of the pipe, which points higher $A$ or $B$ ?

I am sorry if my explanation is hard to understand. I hope someone can help me to solve or give some hints for this problem. Thank you